# How to use setInterval with react useEffect hook correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I tried to create a simple timer app with ReactJS and found the below code on the internet.

Does the function that we passed to the `useEffect` will execute with the dependency change or does it recreates with every dependency change and then execute?

Also I console log the return function of the `useEffect` and it runs with every render. Does it run only when the component unmount? or with every render?

```js
import { useEffect,  useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = React.useState(true);
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (isActive && isPaused === false) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((time) => time + 10);
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("cleanup");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isActive, isPaused]);

  const handleStart = () => {
    setIsActive(true);
    setIsPaused(false);
  };

  const handlePauseResume = () => {
    setIsPaused(!isPaused);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setIsActive(false);
    setTime(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="stop-watch">
      {time}
      <button onClick={handleStart}>start</button>
      <button onClick={handlePauseResume}>pause</button>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>clear</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the `useEffect` hook will run every time a dependency value has been changed. In your case whenever `isActive` or `isPaused` changes state.

This means that the reference to the interval will be lost, as the `interval` variable is redefined.

To keep a steady reference, use the [`useRef`](https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-basics/28/react-useref) hook to have the reference persist throughout state changes.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const interval = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive && !isPaused) {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((time) => time + 10);
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      interval.current = null;
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, [isActive, isPaused])

  ...
}
```

Comment: But the code works. I cant understand how  it clears the interval ? Because with the every dependency change, the reference to the setinterval will be lost. am I correct?

Comment: Well, according to your code the intervals *will* be cleared whenever the component is dismounted, as the `interval` is internally referenced. However, pausing the interval shouldn't work as expected. And yes, the callback function inside `useEffect` will be called every time `isActive` or `isPaused` is changed *and* on the first render.

Comment: If your behavior differs from what I've just described, then please create a runnable example for us to experience your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

/**
 * Timer component
 * 
 * Displays current time and allows user to enter their name
 */
export default function Timer() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0); // current time
    const [name, setName] = useState(""); // user's name

    /**
     * Set up an interval to update the time every second
     * 
     * Returns a function to clear the interval when the component unmounts
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setTime((prev) => prev + 1);
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
    // Only run this effect once, on mount
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    /**
     * Handle changes to the input field
     *
     * @param {Object} event - input change event
     */
    const handleChange = ({ target }) => setName(target.value);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Time: {time}</h1> {/* Display the current time */}
            <input value={name} onChange={handleChange} type="text" /> {/* Display the input field */}
        </>
    );
}
```